# A pokestop wont turn blue after many hours

Tags: pokemon-go

[image]

I have been at a pokestop for a long time. The pokestop won't turn blue after turning purple.  I have tried reinstalling the game, restarting the phone, and turning wifi on and off.

Comment: I believe you are looking for this link which will let you report a problem with a pokestop/gym. https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=319988

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the time of your device, set automatic time from options, I had the same problem. Good Luck!

Comment: How do you know that this isn't how their phone is already configured? The question doesn't mention this being the case, so it's not safe to assume so.

Comment: I had the same problem, I tried every options, and this is the unique funcional tip, My friends had the same problem and the same solution.